# Assembly Programming on the JVM?

Tags: java, scala, assembly, clojure, jvm

I was kind a curious if it was possible to do assembly programming in a similar fashion of using NASM in C.

After quick Google search to see if it was possible to do assembly language programming on the JVM and was surprised to find some results.

Has anyone tried doing something like this before?

I'm also wondering if there are any support assembly support for Clojure or Scala.

[Invoking Assembly Language Programming from Java](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/10/19/invoking-assembly-language-from-java.html)

[minijavac](http://code.google.com/p/minjavac/) : Not in English but it looks like it using some kind of NASM support.

Comment: You need to be clear -- are you talking about "bytecode" assembler or assembler for the native hardware?  And are you expecting to do in-line assembly or will you accept assembling your assembly module separate from compiled code?

Comment: Your question contains your answer.  Use the JNI interface to link to a C file that uses NASM.

Comment: (And, if you're asking how to include native hardware assembly code in a Java app, why would you ever want to?)

Comment: I was wondering if hardware assembly was possible.  I can't think of a good reason to for it expect for shenanigans.

Comment: It's possible but mostly from C/C++, for example in embedded projects. No reason to do that using Java, and Scala is for high-level stuff.

Comment: I can't go to sleep, till I downvote at least once, for programming in assembler is Scala. Especially after macros in 2.10 - absolutely no connection to real stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Assembly is usually used in C so that a) you can access instructions C doesn't generate or b) lower level performance tuning.

As byte code is designed for Java,

- there aren't any useful byte code instructions it doesn't generate
- The JVM looks for common patterns in byte code generated by the compiler and optimises for those.  This means if you write the byte code yourself it is more likely to be less optimised i.e. 
  slower, unless it is the same as what the compiler would produce.

Comment: c) anything that defies the function based regime (functions returning, think ABI ere), though this is mostly only found in system libraries. Calling a syscall, exception helpers etc. d) work around compiler bugs and limitations

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of assembly code.  Byte code doesn't allow these things. Most of the compiler limitations come from limitations in the byte code file format. e.g. the maximum method size.

Comment: Your list (which numbering I kept) was about C. Note that workaround for compiler bugs might also be a reason for external bytecode usage.

Answer (score 2):

Write a JNI library in C with inline assembly in it.

In theory, you could write a JNI-compliant library in *pure* assembly, but why bother?

Comment: Speed, speed, and more speed.  There definitely are people who still need to write assembly these days.  The people I know who do it these days are working on image processing.  They really do lovingly craft each instruction for very performance-critical parts of code.  They can't get close to what they need from a very high-level language like C.

Comment: The difference between C-with-assembly JNI library and pure assembly JNI library will be all in function prologue/epilogue code. There's not much speed to be gained on those. If there is, you're optimizing in the wrong place.

Comment: For fun.  Assembly is dramatically more *fun* to write than boring old C code.  :-)

Comment: Fun (and assembly) does not scale well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point to another solution: generating assembly code at runtime from your java program.
Some (long) time ago there was a project called softwire, written in c++, that did exactly that. It (ab)used (method and operator) overloading to create some kind of c++ DSL that closely resembles x86 ASM, and which behind the scene would assemble the corresponding assembly. The main goal was to be able to dynamically assemble an assembly routine customized for specific configuration, while eliminating nearly all the branchings (the routine would be recompiled if the confiugration changed).
This was an excellent library and the author used to to great effect to implement a software renderer with shading support (shaders were dynamically translated to x86 assembly and the assembled, all at runtime), so this was not just a crazy idea. Unforuntately he was hired by a company and the library acquired in the process.

Today, to follow such a route you could create a JNI binding to [DynAsm](http://luajit.org/dynasm.html) (that alone is probably no small task) and use it to assemble at runtime. If you are willing to use scala over java, you can even relatively easily create a DSL ala softwire, that will under the hood generate the assembly source code and pass it to DynASM.
Sounds like fun :-)
No reason to be bored anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like jasmin project? Because,for some reason for me, minijava always reminds me of jasmin parser...

Comment: Not really, I was just board at work while waiting for a server to start up and was in a mood for some random googling.

Comment: minijava somehow reminds me or jasmin..it was kind of deja vu for me :p